# How to extract the values from the nested Maps using lambdas expression?

Tags: java-8

I need to extract the foreign conversion from the nested map using lambda expression of java 8:
I was able to solve it by the old school of the java 8 for each but wanted to see how it works with the lambda expression of java 8.

e.g i want to filter the maps inside map .

for **cmp1, fee1, Inr-Try**  we have value present as 31. which is desired output

```
   // camp1
        Map<String,String> forexMap3_1 = new HashMap();

        forexMap3_1.put("Eur-Try","11");
        forexMap3_1.put("Usd-Try","21");
        forexMap3_1.put("Inr-Try","31");

        Map<String,String> forexMap3_2= new HashMap();

        forexMap3_2.put("Eur-Try","12");
        forexMap3_2.put("Usd-Try","22");
        forexMap3_2.put("Inr-Try","32");

        Map<String, Map> feeMap2 = new HashMap();

        feeMap2.put("fee1", forexMap3_1);
        feeMap2.put("fee2",forexMap3_2);

        campaigns.put("cmp1", feeMap2);

        // camp2

        Map<String,String> forexMap3_3 = new HashMap();

        forexMap3_3.put("Eur-Try","11");
        forexMap3_3.put("Usd-Try","21");
        forexMap3_3.put("Inr-Try","31");

        Map<String,String> forexMap3_4= new HashMap();

        forexMap3_4.put("Eur-Try","12");
        forexMap3_4.put("Usd-Try","22");
        forexMap3_4.put("Inr-Try","32");

        Map<String, Map> feeMap3 = new HashMap();

        feeMap3.put("fee3", forexMap3_3);
        feeMap3.put("fee4",forexMap3_4);

        campaigns.put("cmp2", feeMap3);
```

Comment: what is your question ? sorry it is not clear to me

Comment: i want output for cmp1, fee1,  Inr-Try  to be 31, here we are trying to loop inside loop of maps to get the right forex amount.

Comment: What is `campaigns`?

Comment: campaign[advertisment campaign]  can have map of fees and fees can have map of forex rates.

Comment: Simple solution without lamda will be :

System.out.println(((HashMap)campaigns.get(campaign).get(fee)).get(forex));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
out.entrySet().stream().filter(x->x.getKey().equals(yourkey)).flatMap(x->x.getValue().entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x.getKey(),x->x.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

just iterate on campaign children:

```
HashMap<String, String> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
campaigns.forEach((s, stringMapMap) -> stringMapMap.forEach((s1, map) -> finalMap.putAll(map)));

System.out.println(finalMap.get("Inr-Try"));   // output: 31
```